# How Can I verify response for different data?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-dataprovider

1. I am using DataProvider concept in testng.  The below method will run    5 times for a different users. The same method will run for 5 times but different input and different output.I want to assert the response.
2. Is there any best way to capture and assert response, the flow of one couldn't affects another?

> ```
> DataProvider: paginationData.csv  
>             USER,CURRENT_PAGE,PER_PAGE,SORT,EXPECTED_STATUS_CODE
>             A,1,22,created_at,200
>             B,1,22,updated_at,200
>             C,1,22,name,200
>             D,1,22,id,200
>             E,1,22,invalid,200
> ```

```
        @Test(dataProvider = "paginationData", dataProviderClass = ADataProvider.class)
        public void getSrcPagination(String user, String current_page, String per_page, String sort,
                int statusCode) {
            String token = getAuthHeader(user);
            String url = SrcHelper.getUrlPagination(SrcHelper.URI, current_page, per_page, sort);
            Response res = getRequest(url, token, statusCode);
            res.prettyPrint();
        }
```

Comment: Why not add the expected output as one of the DataProvider parameters? After all, you know what to expect when you give a certain input, right?

Comment: @selvi, You can't assert with status code which you are getting for each array ?